#  Check With JMeter that redirection to website mobile version works

Tags: jmeter

If users access the site through the main website they should be automatically redirected to the mobile version. Is there a way to test in Jmeter if all the mobile users are redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a test using:

- a csv config element that will contain the list of user-agents iphone, samsung galaxy s3...
- one http sampler per mobile version of site as  you have 5 mobile websites
- as a child of this request a  headermanager with user-agent set to variable defined in csv

And set the number of iterations to the number of lines in csv.

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com

Comment: #Thank you very much for the answer.#

But I'm not sure if adding mobile agents is really reasonable as there is a huge number of them. Could you please tell me if thee is any way to make it more efficiently?
And could you please also give a suggestion of what is better to do f there is a number of sites which should be checked instead if the oinly one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, i proposed a solution that simplifies test plan, but you still need to provide user agent list in csv

Comment: I don't understand your second question about number of sites

Comment: It's my fault, I'm really sorry. I'm just newbie to Jmeter. Here is the point: 1. There are 5 websites with mobile versions provided. 2. I should check that when user sends request from mobile device – mobile version of site is shown. Could you please give me any suggestion on how to make this script read URLs of these sites from CSV file? Does your previous answer mean I should create 2 CSV config elements? Thank you for your patience.